# React modal bootstrap closeButton not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-bootstrap

I have added logic for providers on react app using react bootstrap Modal. When I click on close button it is not working. Please find my logic.

```
import React from 'react';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
     
export class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        show: false
    }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState ({show: false})
  }
  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState ({show: true})
  }

  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
          show={this.handleShow}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          dialogClassName="modal-50w"
      >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Login using below account</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
          </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export { firebase, database as default };
```

Please help me to fix this issue. I did google search, but i didn't find answer for this fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` attribute of the `Modal` takes `boolean` value.

`show={this.handleShow}` should be `show={this.state.show}`

Comment: exactly, the show prop expects a variable to follow, is not going to execute the function you are providing.